# Make cookies not read-only

Tags: javascript, cookies

Making a game and trying to save an array of completed levels to a cookie.  This works very well when the cookie is first made however when you go back later to continue playing the cookie appears to be read-only and does not change as it did before reloading the page.

Something like: `var completedLevels = [1,1,0,0,0,0,0];` is editable on the first run through the game, but if you close the game and come back the array is locked in whatever state it was previously in, ie: `[1,1,0,0,0,0,0]` in this case.

This is obviously not really the behavior I was looking for so am wondering if there's a way to make the cookie not read-only on creation or something like that.  My research thus far seems to indicate that cookies are never read-only be default which makes me a little suspicious but since I haven't done much with cookies in the past I'm rather confused!

EDIT:
When you first play the game the array is: `[0,0,0,0,...]`, then the user completes level 1 and the array updates so it's now: `[1,0,0,0,...]`, level 2: `[1,1,0,0,...]` and so on.  When a level is completed that array is put into a cookie: `document.cookie = "completedLevels=" + this.completedArr + "; expires=Mon, 3 April 2034 20:47:11 UTC path=/";`.  Now say you've played through levels 1,2, and 4, so the array looks like this: `[1,1,0,1,...]`, you close the page, come back later and expect to be able to play level 3.  When you finish that level, the same code that before would have updated the array to `[1,1,1,1,...]` updates the version the code works with but NOT the cookie.

Comment: Please show us your ACTUAL code as this sounds more like there's a problem with your code (especially since there aren't read-only cookies).  You also ought to know that you can't just put an array in a cookie.  You have to turn the array into a string first as cookies are only strings.

Comment: Is the game client-side/JS only, or is there server code? What is setting the cookie? What is reading a cookie. What do you mean by "locked in whatever state it was previously in?" Show code, get specific.

Comment: client side, see edit for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to convert back from string to array when the data is being reloaded.  both localStorage and cookies use strings and so my concatenation was implicitly converting from an array to a string.  When you closed the page and reopened it the data was loaded back as a string and dumped into a var that was supposed to be an array, which obviously caused problems.